# import cv2 causing Library not loaded: @rpath/libtiff.5.dylib error

Tags: python, macos, opencv, jupyter-notebook, conda-forge

Using homebrew I installed miniconda and a number of python packages from
[Installing TensorFlow and Jupyter Notebook on Apple Silicon Macs](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-and-jupyter-notebook-on-apple-silicon-macs-d30b14c74a08)

I had good success with a number of notebooks but run into an issue with a notebook starting with:

import cv2

getting errors starting with

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/python-3.10/cv2.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libtiff.5.dylib
```

I've tried reinstalling conda, etc. without success. any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: conda-forge packages are third-party. use official opencv packages, from PyPI (pip).